# Not able to generate .class file in maven project

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven

Not able to create .class files in the target folder after building.I  maven for building the app, clean install cmd not creating the .class files , could any onetell me whether directory strutire needs to be changed or ??

Comment: Where are your Java file located? src/main/java ? Any error? How does your pom file look like?

Comment: created my packages called com/java/actions,com/java/services...

Comment: I didn't ask how your packages are named. I asked where are your source files located?

Comment: What is the error message, if any?  What is the folder structure of your project (as @khmarbaise asked)?

Comment: src- main-com- (contains all java file),resources(all xmls),webapps(jsp,WEB-INF).Error message while starting the server is :Unable to load configuation  action - file:/F:/softwares/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:14:67

Comment: after googling,the directory structure is  not correct , iam not able to create project structure that is suitable for Maven,could any one help me out

Comment: You can use an archetype based on your need. This will generate a standard project template. http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/. Also, by default, java files should be in /src/main/java

Answer (score 6):

From the comment, it looks your project does not follow maven convention for folder structure.

As  @user474249 commented, you could use the [maven archetype plugin](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/) to generate a folder structure based on your project type (jar/war), etc.

Otherwise, you could manually alter the folder structure as per maven convention. For web projects

- src/main/java - java source
- src/main/resources - java resources
- src/main/webapp - web resources
- src/test/java - java tests
- src/test/resources - test resources

If that is not feasible either, you can indicate your specific locations to maven as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html). For instance,

```
<sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/</sourceDirectory>
```

Comment: I have altered folder structure manually, now iam able to create .class files .

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, especially on migrating from Ant to Maven

Answer (score 2):

The bytecode is in `target/classes` if not then:

```
mvn clean compile -X
```

so we can see some debug info in the  compile phase.

You can also try this:

```
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Strictly to debug since it should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Following maven command solved my problem. Hopes it will help others.

```
                       mvn clean install
```